# Can we have multiple validations in a HTML form?

Tags: html, validation

I'm new in HTML and I want to have two types of validation for a single constant. For example, for "name" I want it to be required and also start with an Uppercase letter, with a maximum length and minimum length. Can I put two < input > lines in my html or will it give me an error?

Example of my Code:

```
            <div class="input-field">

                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control validate"><br></br>
                <label for="name">Name
                 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                 <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-zA-Z]{3,30}">
                    <span class="red-text"> *</span>
                </label>
            </div>
```

I am also looking for email validation, i only want to allow @gmail and @yahoo format.. I've been googling for hours but I can't find it, could someone help me with that as well?

Comment: @MisterJojo so what i wrote is correct?

Comment: @MisterJojo oh, so I should put both required and pattern on the same input line and it will work? Also, thank you very much for helping me

Comment: @MisterJojo thank youu so much, you made my night lol. I am trying to learn Js too but i've only learned very basic things and i don't know how to work with it well yet. But thank you, once again!! :D